# Add value from specific row in a dataset filtered by a parameter to textbox

Tags: reporting-services

I expect this to be easy, but I haven't found a solution.
I have a textbox that will hold a description. However this description exists in a dataset that has an id and a description. The id I need is supplied as a parameter. So all I need to do is somehow "search" that dataset based on the value of the parameter, and retrieve the description I need and add this to a textbox.

I have tried -

```
Lookup(Parameters!Id.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Desc.Value, "DatasetName")
```

but it doesn't seem to like that.

Anyone know what to do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this to work with a different example, using:

```
=lookup(Fields!FilmDirectorID.Value,Fields!DirectorID.Value,Fields!DirectorName.Value, "DataSet2")
```

Your syntax looks OK, but you've misspelt **Parameters**.  This could be the problem?